# Insert data from html form

Tags: php, html, forms

im new to HTML and PHP. I am trying to create a form which loads my new users details into a database hosted by my web hosting company.

my form code (HTML) is :

```
  <h1>Create Your GoSense Account</h1>
  <form method:"POST" action:"newuserform.php" >
  <div class="namef">
  Name: <input type="text" style="width:200px" name="Name"  
  placeholder="First Name"><br></br> </div>
  <div class="surnamef">
  Surname: <input type="text" style="width:178px" name="Surname" 
  placeholder="Last Name"><br></br></div>
  <div class="emailf">
  Email: <input type="text" style="width:202px" name="Email" 
  placeholder="Email"><br></br> </div>
  <div class="passwordf">
  Password: <input type="text" style="width:170px" name="Password" 
  placeholder="Password"><br></br></div>
  <input type="submit" style="font-size: 300px" name="" 
  value="Submit">
  </form>
```

my PHP code stored in newuserform.php is:

```
<?php

define('DB_NAME','gosensec_useraccounts');
define('DB_USER','MyUsername');
define('DB_PASSWORD','myPassword');
define('DB_HOST','***.**.**.**');

$Name = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'Name');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

$db_selected = mysql_select_db (DB_NAME, $link) ;

$VALUE = $_POST['Name'];
$VALUE = $_POST['Surname'];
$VALUE = $_POST['Email'];
$VALUE = $_POST['Password'];

$sql = " INSERT INTO Users (Name) VALUES ('$VALUE')";
$sql = " INSERT INTO Users (Surname) VALUES ('$VALUE')";
$sql = " INSERT INTO Users (Email) VALUES ('$VALUE')";
$sql = " INSERT INTO Users (Password) VALUES ('$VALUE')";

mysql_close()

?>
```

I have doubled checked the connection parameters with my db host company and they advised that it is correct so my next step is to question my code ? Can anyone pick any errors that could be causing the data to insert into my DB ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Since you are still learning I'd suggest you to learn PDO instead of Mysql_* API for connecting a DB to PHP. Mysql has been removed since PHP 7 and was deprecated since 5. Also look for prepared statements to prevent SQL injections

Comment: BTW the reason why you see no results here is that your webserver is using PHP7. If you turn on error reporting in PHP (google for it and you will find how) you will get the error

Comment: `<form method:"POST" action:"newuserform.php" >` that is wrong syntax.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple mistakes.

**1-** Assign each variable to a specific name:

```
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Surname = $_POST['Surname'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Password = $_POST['Password'];
```

**2-** insert all values into a single row not multiple rows.Also concatnate the variables as variables not as strings inside quotes!

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (Name,Surname,Email,Password) VALUES ('" .$Name. "','". $Surname ."','". $Email ."','" .$Password. "')";
```

**3-** Do not forget to execute sql command:

```
$link->query($sql)
```

**4-** To close the connection use `mysql_close($link)`

**finally**: Do not forget to [prevent *SQL INJECTION*](https://www.shift8web.ca/2015/06/securing-your-mysql-queries-from-sql-injection-in-php/) by filtering values. Also try [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead of the discontinued mysql API.

Comment: Thanks so Ali, much appreciated.  I have made the changes you have recommended.  just two questions  1. as mentioned im new to html / php , what code would i use to prevent SQL injection ? also what code would i use to close off the connection . i tried using mysql_close() but my editor says the syntax is incorrect

Comment: you should mention in your answer that OP is using a discontinued API and that this is time to start using mysqli_* at least or better PDO

Comment: for closing connection you have to use `mysql_close($link)` @Alex

Comment: Please check the links to `mysqli documentation` and `sql injection prevention` in edited answer. @Alex

Comment: Thanks Ali - Just updated my code and unfortunately the form is still not inserting the data into the DB. Any ideas on what could be causing this ?

Comment: Please Add you updated code at the end of main question. @Alex

Comment: Thanks Ali, sure thing. will copy and paste now.

Comment: you missed the part about their form syntax.